# Echoing a URL to a link

Tags: escaping

I've found the [esc_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) function and I'm trying to understand what to do with URLs in Wordpress, before resorting to my normal PHP tactics. I see that the [third parameter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3355) is used to set the filter that runs on it, with the default value of 'display'. This is for display on a webpage. I grepped the WP source code for examples of the use of the third parameter and found but a single example:

```
$ grep -rP "esc_url.*\([^\)\,]*\,[^\)\,]*\, ?'?\"?.*\)" *
wp-includes/formatting.php: return esc_url( $url, $protocols, 'db' );
```

All other matches to `grep` were for irrelevant invocations, such as the use of another function call's return value as an `esc_url()` argument.

**Other than 'display' and 'db', what other values should be used and when?** I see quite a few places in the WP source code where the display value is used in an href, here is an example:

```
$ grep -r esc_url * | grep href
wp-admin/themes.php: <td><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $delete_url ); ?>" class="button button-secondary delete-theme"><?php _e( 'Delete' ); ?></a></td>
```

**Should the 'display' value really be used for an href attribute?** It seems to me that it does some encoding that I would not trust to return always to proper URL afterward, especially for non-ASCII URLs.

Is this a bug in WP that the 'dispaly' filter is being used for actual URLs, or should I use the 'display' filter for actual URLs in my own code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other value can be used in place of `display` and `db`.

WordPress just check for value `display` and convert `&` and `'`quotes to `HTML` entities (Including all other characters). If you pass `db` it is just skip this block of code.
However, WordPress recommends to use `esc_url_raw()` instead of passing third argument.

You can use `esc_url_raw()` when saving back-end options like theme options or plugin settings and you should always `esc_url()` in `href` attribute, browser decodes it very well.